# Unknown column error after changing a field to foreign key in django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I changed one of the field from IntegerField to ForeignKey. Migrations went well and query is working in mysql but when i start the server and load the homepage i get this error

> (1054, "Unknown column 'job_test.suite_id_id' in 'field list'")

where job_test is a table and suite_id is a foreign key referencing to another table.

Please help.

Answer (score 3):

As documented under [ForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey):

> #### Database Representation
>
> Behind the scenes, Django appends **"_id"** to the field name to create its database column name. In the above example, the database table for the **Car** model will have a **manufacturer_id** column. (You can change this explicitly by specifying [**db_column**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.db_column)) However, your code should never have to deal with the database column name, unless you write custom SQL. You’ll always deal with the field names of your model object.

Therefore you need to rename your field to `suite` instead of `suite_id`, or else specify [`db_column`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.db_column) to override the column name Django is trying to use.